# My Aquaris E4.5 doesn't connect via USB after OTA-10

Tags: usb, aquaris

Yesterday I downloaded the OTA-10 system upgrade on my Aquaris E4.5, and now when I connect it to my Ubuntu laptop using a USB cable, the laptop no longer automounts the phone and its SD card. :-( Any help from someone more knowledgeable would be warmly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Now I fixed the problem: you have to use gmtp on the laptop